# Align digits with brill font

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, polyglossia

I'm using the polyglossia package with Brill as main font and works perfectly except for the fact that all digits appear in a lower case. Does anybody know how to align them with the other letters?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}
\setmainfont{Brill}
\begin{document} 
 abdc1234 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the font contain upper case digits? If not, you can use the work-around of putting numbers into math mode. This can also be used to distinguish ordinal from cardinal numbers in a text. (I hope I remember those words right). There are some answers on the site that deal with replacing fonts for a subset of characters; This may be another solution if you have lots of numbers.

Comment: Just as a point of information...what you are calling "lower case numbers" are commonly referred to as "old style figures" or "OSF".

Comment: Observe that your query isn't actually related to the `polyglossia` package *per se*. It just to happens that the `polyglossia` package automatically loads the `fontspec` package (if it hasn't been loaded already); it's the `fontspec` package that provides the macro `\setmainfont`.

Answer (score 7):

Brill’s default numbers are lowercase and proportional.  For uppercase, proportional figures, simply use

```
\setmainfont{Brill}[Numbers=Lining]
```

For uppercase, tabular figures, use

```
\setmainfont{Brill}[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]
```